# Creating a web based, interactive, remotely polled terminal emulator

Tags: shell, perl, command-line

I have updated this to clarify my question...

Originally I asked for a good method of running commands in a persistent session such that I could send a command, get a response, and rinse and repeat. It seems that clarification of my end goal might be more useful for the folks willing to give me suggestions as perhaps the solution is not in the direction I initially was headed. So, here is the low down :)

My HUGE thank you to everyone that has helped so far and to those who stop to help.

I am working on a script that will securely allow me to use an internally hosted webpage (password protected and encrypted) to run commands on the command line and retrieve the output.

I know that there are things like shellinabox and ajaxTerm that allow browser based SSH and that is my end goal... sort of... with a catch...

I need to have a single server that hosts the terminal emulator. It should allow one to log into the terminal emulator and use it as if it were local, HOWEVER any and all commands should be proxied to a remote client which RETRIEVES the commands by querying for them, running them, and then returning the results and terminal output to the main server. The parent script takes commands, puts them into the db, and then waits for a result, which it displays, before allowing further commands. The script will be looping with a sleep and an automatic throttle so the created handle would stay open until the remote session has been idle for a certain amount of time or sends a disconnect.

Originally, from my research and brainstorming it seemed best to use OPEN to get a handle to the shell. To that end I did a good bit of googling and, while this seems simple, I am coming up empty on a good way to proxy a shell session in the manner I wish.

Could anyone offer a suggestion that might work? I would love to use one of the already available open source terminals and figure out how to make it 'start' a session without actually starting a session so that the remote side could connect in, retrieve, and run the results then pass back data.

**The basic steps**

1) User opens web based terminal hosted on server A.
2) Session immediately appears to be 'open'.
3) User enters a command.
4) Terminal accepts command and waits
5) Client machine on the other side of the internet checks in and sees that there is a command waiting for it so it grabs it
6) Client machine starts a session and runs that command
7) Client machine returns the results and begins to loop looking for more   commands
8) Server A gets the result and returns it to the web based terminal
9) User sees the result and the terminal is now ready to accept another command
10) This continues until no commands have been issued for awhile at which point the session exits and the remote side goes back to only checking for commands occasionally

I have all of the secure stuff written and working very well. I have the checking for commands, passing back and forth, auto throttling when idle, database logging, etc working... I just don't want to re-invent the wheel virtual terminal wise and command digesting wise... but I have no idea how to best do this. To that end I was trying to come up with my own basic command management code. The problem is that is re-inventing the wheel and it's a more complicated wheel than I care to carve...

It seems to me that the best bet is to somehow 'split' one of the web based, open source, virtual terminal emulators in half such that I intercept the commands, cache them in the db, then return them from the db so that it looks to the emulator as if it is local and just slow, when in reality it is remote...

I recognize that this may all be a bit confusing so please let me know if this all makes sense or if I can clarify more.

**EDIT**

Here is what I have so far for command digestion that sort of works... This is just interactive sample. The real commands would be sent and received remotely. I say sort of because certain things like ping break it. vi breaks it as well but that is to be expected... though I would love suggestions for a work around.

This is quick and ugly but works for basic stuff. I'm sure it is a bit dangerous as far as creating zombie processes but I'll focus on that later.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;
use IO::Select;

#connect to our session using sudo
my $pid = open3(\*WRITE, \*READ,\*ERROR,"sudo su");
my $checkRead = new IO::Select();
my $checkError = new IO::Select();
$checkRead->add(\*READ);
$checkError->add(\*ERROR);
#hold it
my $query  = '';

#want to do it at least once...
do{
    my $error  = '';
    my $answer = '';
    #give us a prompt
    print "\n[REM PROMPT]# ";
    $query = <STDIN>;
    chomp($query);
    #make sure we aren't exiting
    if($query !~/^EXIT\s*$/){
        #send what we entered
        print WRITE "$query\n";
        #We need to give this a chance to run
        select(undef,undef,undef,.02);

        #get any error from bc 
        sysread(ERROR,$error,8192) if $checkError->can_read(0);
        if($error){print "\e[1;31m ERROR: $error \e[0m \n"}

        #get the answer from bc 
        sysread(READ,$answer,8192) if $checkRead->can_read(0);
        if($answer){ print "$answer\n"; }
    }
#give us a way to get out
}while($query !~/^EXIT\s*$/);
#make sure it all exits
waitpid($pid, 1);
```

The problem with the above is that while I can pass basic commands to and from it 1) it chokes on anything that is a sub process 2) I would need to re-invent a web based terminal 3) it is likely no good with zombie processes...

Any helpful thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) would be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks mob! I'll play around with this.

Comment: *"To that end it seem impractical to use backticks as I would need to track the path constantly..."* What do you mean by *"use backticks"*?

Comment: Hi Håkon, what I mean by that is I can't do $result = `ls`; because each time I call something to the back ticks it will be a fresh session and so I won't be able to be interactive to whatever is going on. 

So far Expect does seem to be a good option!

Comment: @yesterdayze I am not sure I completely understand your setup, but I think you could also try using [`AnyEvent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent) and let the parent and child communicate over a socket for example.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) can maintain a session between commands rather than opening a new session for each. But Expect is still better for responding to prompts.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas. I have been busy playing with these and have made some progress but not quite where I want to be yet. 

Ideally I want to emulate a basic terminal. I would love to be able to support things like opening vi and interacting with it, but, at the very least I want to support basic commands and prompts. I did manage to get a very basic interaction using IPC Open2 but once I open vi (for example) I can no longer interact. I assume expect is the better solution but I'm having trouble understanding how to make it return without match patterns.